# Writing list of dictionaries in python to csv with specific field order

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of dictionaries, lst with random key:value pairs. I also have a list - the order in which I want to write fields into the csv file(Essentialy keys of dictionary). I used the code below to write the csv file.

```
lst=[{"b":2,"d":3},{"a":1,"b":1,"c":5},{"d":7,"c":1}...]  
order = ["a","b","c","d"]

keys = lst[index].keys()
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(lst)
```

The final CSV file has keys in the order:

```
b,d,a,c  
2,3,,
```

But I want it according to the order list. How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you passing `lst[index].keys()` instead of `order`?

Comment: @BrenBarn: Do you want to put that down as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet produces your desired output

```
lst=[{"b":2,"d":3},{"a":1,"b":1,"c":5},{"d":7,"c":1}]  
order = ["a","b","c","d"]
with open('file.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, order)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You never used `order`.  Just pass that instead of `keys` when you create your DictWriter.

Answer (score 0):

first get all the keys from list of dict
second sort the list of keys base on your order list
final write the header based on sorted keys

```
lst = [{'b': 2, 'd': 3}, {'a': 1, 'c': 5, 'b': 1}, {'c': 1, 'd': 7}]
flatLst = set([ k for ele in lst for k in ele.keys()])
def sortKey(x):
    return order.index(x) if x in order else len(order)
orderedHeader = sorted( flatLst, key = lambda x:sortKey(x))
with open(filePath,'wb') as f:
     w = csv.DictWriter(f,orderedHeader)
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(lst)
```

output:

```
a   b   c   d
    2       3
1   1   5   
        1   7
```